# CSS: Circle with half one color and the other half another color?

Tags: css

Is it possible to do something like this with CSS? Basically make half the circle one color and the other half another color?
[image]

Comment: Of course it is. What have you tried and where did you get stuck? Post your code please.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: I don't know how, so I'm looking for some guidance here.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

A `linear-gradient` will do that, and use `border-radius` to make it a circle.

```css
div {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vw;
  background: linear-gradient( -45deg, blue, blue 49%, white 49%, white 51%, red 51% ); 
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like this:

```css
div {
    border-radius: 50px;
    border-right-color: red;
    border-top-color: blue;
    border-bottom-color: red;
    border-left-color: blue;
    border-width: 50px;
    border-style: solid;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    }
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements for each half of circle and also add `transform: rotate()` on parent element.

```css
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotate(25deg);
}
.circle:after, .circle:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}
.circle:after {
  background: #02FBFD;
  left: -2px;
}
.circle:before {
  background: #FE0103;
  right: -2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```